# How to implement load more posts in Next js without losing previously fetched data?

Tags: next.js, pagination, infinite-scroll, next.js13

Scenario: I get datas from api with page and other queries, and when i am at 3rd pages with load more clicks (all datas are there of 1-3 pages), and then i clicked and navigate to other page and come back then it's lost it's datas? **I mean how can i handle to store datas without losing it when page change**? and Implement Load more posts? any Idea?

**Summary:**
Search Page >> Click Load more button 3 times >> click one of item and go inside of that page >> return back to search page

when i complete this cycle the previously fetched datas are reset in client-side! explain me solution or give code sample.